# Making a C# project DLL and EXE

Tags: c#, dll

I'm working on a project where I need to have both an executable so that the user can run a configuration interface and a DLL that can be embedded in other projects to use some of the other features. Is there a way to make Visual Studio produce both an executable and a DLL (as opposed to switching it manually every time)?

Comment: Can you give a few more details about the project and how it is going to be deployed etc.

Comment: I have this same problem. The answer, as has been said, is to make two projects, and for the dll and one for the exe, depending on the dll. The obvious disadvantage here is that now you have two files to deal with when you use the exe. :( Oh well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with TJMonk15, but i think this should be explained explicitly. You should have two projects, one project that is a DLL, and one that is a normal project. The DLL project should have all your re-usable code. The normal project should be the application you are building, which will reference your re-usable DLL. This way you can build a framework in the DLL project that can be used for any of your future projects.

A good example of this is when you are making a game. Your game engine would be the DLL, and the game you are making would be the executable project. The executable project will contain all the non-reusable traits such as game GUIs and content.

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't you put most of the code in one project (With an ouput of type Library) and then write an executable that referenes the DLL?

Comment: This would have been the way to go. Sadly, I didn't consider this when starting the project, and I want to avoid having to move everything around, since everything works at this point...

Comment: You cant still reference an exe iirc from another project

Comment: @user472875 If you wrote your code in an Object-Oriented fashion, with re-usability in mind, it would be fairly easy to just create two new projects and separate out the code that needs to go in the DLL and the code that needs to go in the EXE project.

Comment: @TJMonk: I'm assuming that "t" was a typo, because you CAN reference pure MSIL exe assemblies (which the C# compiler generates) in the same way as DLL assemblies.

Comment: I would probably go with the approach of separating out the code into two files.  Depending on the size of your project and deployment method I wouldn't think that this would take more than a couple of hours\day max.   In the long run it would be well worth your time.

Comment: Based on everyone's  comments, I decided to separate the code into 2 projects. I think it will save me tons of headache as things keep moving. Thanks all.